# NSMutableArray with custom object invalid attributes

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsuserdefaults, nsobject, nscoding

I have saved a nsmutable array with custom objects in the NSUserDefault. But when I am retrieving I got a array with the objects, but when I am trying to iterate through the objects the app crash and in the local debugger I got invalid

> CFStringRef and the log -[Message title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x187900.

My custom object follow the NSCoding protocol and If I print out the array, is showing the object and the memory allocating in hex.

My Message. I had changed name to the attributes for testing:

```
  #import "Message.h"

  @implementation Message
  @synthesize tittel, adresse, dato;
  static NSString *titleKey = @"title";
  static NSString *urlKey = @"url";
  static NSString *dateKey = @"date";

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
      self.tittel = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:titleKey];
       self.adresse = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:urlKey];
      self.dato = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:dateKey];
   }
   return self;
}   

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:self.tittel forKey:titleKey];
[encoder encodeObject:self.adresse  forKey:urlKey];
[encoder encodeObject:self.dato forKey:dateKey];

 }

-(void)dealloc{

[dato release];
[tittel release];
[adresse release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Methods where I save and try to retrieve the objects:

-(void)saveToFile:(NSMutableArray *)incoming{

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (standardUserDefault) {

    [standardUserDefault setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:incoming]] forKey:@"Messages"];
    [standardUserDefault synchronize];
}

 NSLog(@"Messages array saved. (%d message in array)",[incoming count]);

}
-(NSMutableArray*)returnFromFile{

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData * dataCheck = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:[standardUserDefault objectForKey:@"Messages"]];

NSMutableArray *retro;
if(dataCheck != nil){
    NSArray *load = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataCheck];
    if(load != nil){
        retro = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:load];
    }
    else
        retro = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
NSLog(@"Checking saved array (%d assignments in array)",[retro count]);

for(Message *m in retro){
   NSLog(@"%@", m.tittel);   //It crash here. 

}

return retro;
```

}

Comment: Does your class `Message` have property `title`?

Comment: can u do the same operation (whatever you try after getting it back from userDefaults) on the array before adding it to the NSUserDefults?

Comment: I tried with message.adresse with same result.

Comment: @Nekto: yes, it have. I tried to change the name over the whole line for testing, and give me same problem.

Comment: If you log just m, instead of m.tittel, what do you see?

Comment: No one that can help? I will try building with different machine and phone today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it!

Just made a new class, almost the same. Only difference is that I used a standard init method where I initiate all the attributes and the initWithCoder. And it worked. It happen before that if the gcc have had an error or I try to compile a class that not following the protocols that continue to show the same error. That sometimes it help create something exactly the same or with minors difference and compile. Looks like the compiler not always flush the memory.